# $("<img/>").attr("src",something).load() not supported in IE < 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qDqZF/

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', "http://derek1906.site50.net/navbar/images/pic3.png").load(function() {
    $("body").html("done");
   blah blah blah...
})
```

There I have tested using `$("<img/>").load` in IE 7, and what I got are these:

When run in counsel, I get this:

> "Unable to get value of the property 'attr': object is null or undefined"

When used in my webpage, I get this:

> "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'slice': object is null or undefined"
>   jquery.js, line 2 character 32039

What happened? (Hate IE...)

Comment: Posting as comment instead of answer since I'm not sure this is the problem. In IE you need to add an element to the DOM before you can attach an event to it, if I recall correctly.

Comment: But it works on Chrome, Firefox.... why not IE?

Comment: I ran your fiddle in IE8 and it worked the same as in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the load function is being executed. I recently dealt with this issue. In IE the load function wasn't firing on cached images. For my purposes I was able to get around this by never allowing the image to cache. ( An ugly solution )

ex:

```
src="loremIpsum.jpg"
```

change to:

```
src="loremIpsum.jpg?nocache=" + new Date().getTime()
```

Where "nocache" can be changed to anything that makes sense to you.

From the jQuery documentaion:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the `.load()` shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache"
>   http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

In IE the load event doesn't always get triggered when the image is cached. Try this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://derek1906.site50.net//navbar/images/pic3.png";
if (img.complete || img.readyState === 4) {
    $("body").html("done");
}
else {
    $(img).on("load error onreadystatechange",function(e){
        if (e.type === "error") {
            $("body").html("Image failed to load.");
        }
        else {
            $("body").html("done");
        }
    });
}
```

Also, don't forget to wait for the `DOMReady` event, otherwise `$("body")` may not exist yet if the image loads fast enough.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDqZF/1/)**

Edit:

I have a plugin that may help simplify image preloading: https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-preloadImages/

Answer (score 0):

So I did some quick testing in jfidde, and pulled out the relevant code and ran it standalone in ie7-8-9. They all ran fine. I can say with confidence that it is not this piece of code that is breaking your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo by DerekL</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('<img/>').attr('src', "http://derek1906.site50.net//navbar/images/pic3.png").load(function() {
        $("body").html("done");
        $("<img/>").appendTo("body").attr("src","http://derek1906.site50.net//navbar/images/pic3.png");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Loading...
</body>
</html>
```

Some ideas though:

1. Wrap any script in the document head that manipulates the DOM in a document.ready call.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){ go(); });
   ```
2. Search your source code for that slice call. If you are trying to manipulate a jQuery collection with .slice() it will break. jQuery collections are Objects, not Arrays. (may or may not be your problem)
3. Make sure that any code trying to touch that image is called after the .load() method returns. A common mistake is to do something like:

   ```
   $('<img id="me" />').attr('src', 'my.jpeg')
                       .load( function(){ $(this).appendTo("body"); } );
   alert( $('#me').attr('src') );
   ```

If this is the only image on the page, the above script will likely fail because the appendTo() is called asyncronously, and almost certianly *after* the following lines of code have executed and failed. Make sure that any logic manipulating that image is run from the .load() callback. (As you have nicely done in your above example code.)

If you paste the rest of your page source I can take a look! Good luck!

Comment: @Johny Fuchs, I didn't use any `.slice()` in [my website](http://derek1906.site50.net)... I can't figure out if the image preloading part is not the one that break my page, then what is it Awww, debugging in IE is so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

add load event first then set img'src
because ie run so fast than when you set the src, "load" event was finished
 the new load handler will be executed next change